# C# Dll in C++, how to

Tags: c++

How can i add a .dll compiled in C# in C++ and call certain function? I am using Visual C# AND C++ 2010. I have a dll written in c# and i want to use that function in c++, What is the simplest way to do this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

Make a C# library class.  Build it.  Add a reference to it in the C++ project.  Use it.  I'm confident it works but I've never taken C# into C++ using the technique, however given the properties of the CIL it should work.

Answer (score 0):

The only real easy way to do this assuming your are using c++ classes is to create a c++/cli bridge between the c++ and c#. The other way is to create a com interface from the c# dll and use it in c++ that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using C++/CLI, it should Just Work. If you are using native C++, then it is more complicated. COM interop is probably the way to go in that case.

Comment: Im creating native c++ dll in vs2010 and use c# dll function in it, i didnt create c++/CLI brdige what should i do now?

Comment: Com interop is your only answer.